RowTooBigException when using allowPartialResults
I'm getting:

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException:
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RowTooBigException: Max row size
allowed: 1073741824, but the row is bigger than that, the row info:
REDACTED, already have process row cells = 1756863, it belong to
region = REDACTED

Scanner (has more stuff but thats what I think is relevant):
scanner.setCaching(50); // Tried 1 as well, same issue
scanner.setAllowPartialResults(true);
scanner.setMaxResultSize(20 * 1024 * 1024);

It also has some filters. One of them is KeyOnlyFilter to try and avoid this exact problem.
Cell size limit is default (10MB).
So I don't get it. With allowPartialResults this shouldn't happen, so why am I still getting that?
